# Group by like SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by, case

I have a table (reason_table) with data (eg) :

```
request_id          created_time            type             detail
asdas232          2018-07-29 00:00:01      NO_VALID        No valid offer for id asdas232
aseeas232         2018-07-29 00:00:02      NO_VALID        Not default offer for id aseeas232
```

I am trying to get the count based on detail like(for the above) :

```
invalidOffer = 1
NoDefaultOffer = 1
```

I tried :

```
SELECT detail, count(*)
FROM reason_table 
where "type" like '%NO_VALID%'
and created_time >=  '2018-07-29 00:00:00'
and created_time <=  '2018-07-29 00:00:10'
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN detail LIKE '%invalid%' THEN 'invalidOffer'
        WHEN detail LIKE '%default%' THEN 'NoDefaultOffer'
        ELSE NULL
    END
```

but getting error saying `SQL Error [500310] [42803]: [ Invalid operation: column "detail" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;`

Can some help me find what I am doing wrong here ?
I am using DBeaver to query data from redshift

Comment: You are grouping by a column that isn't in the result set. What are you trying to do here? and which DBMS are you using? sql server <> mysql.

Comment: To be a little pedantic... It's not that they are grouping by a column not in the result set; that is actually fairly common. It is that they are selecting a column not in the `group by` list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the expression to the `select`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN detail LIKE '%invalid%' THEN 'invalidOffer'
             WHEN detail LIKE '%default%' THEN 'NoDefaultOffer'
        END) as detail_group,
        count(*)
FROM reason_table 
WHERE "type" like '%NO_VALID%' AND
      created_time >=  '2018-07-29 00:00:00' AND
      created_time <=  '2018-07-29 00:00:10'
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN detail LIKE '%invalid%' THEN 'invalidOffer'
               WHEN detail LIKE '%default%' THEN 'NoDefaultOffer'
          END);
```

Comment: SELECT (CASE WHEN detail LIKE '%invalid%' THEN 'invalidOffer'
               WHEN detail LIKE '%default%' THEN 'NoDefaultOffer'
          END) as detail_group,
        count(*)
FROM reason_table 
WHERE "type" like '%NO_VALID%' AND
      created_time >=  '2018-07-29 00:00:00' AND
      created_time <=  '2018-07-29 00:00:10' wouldn't this be sufficient why additional group by ?